# Will bootstrap be removed from spartacus-storefront

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are about to start a spartacus-storefront project (1.3.1) and in the docs it is mentioned that for Q1 2020 the removal of ng Bootstrap is planned.

https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/spartacus-roadmap/#move-to-angular-9--ivy

What will this mean for projects we start now and base on bootstrap? If we want to upgrade in the near future and we based our components on bootstrap will we need to refactor a lot? It is kind of a black box for me what the implications will be.

Answer (score 4):

ngBootstrap functionality will be removed from Spartacus in 2.0 but bootstrap styles will not be removed as a dependency in the styles library as of then. You can always import bootstrap into your projects even if it is removed from Spartacus.

~ Caine from Spartacus Core Team

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's usually good to provide the source for your answer, if possible, so the person asking the question as well as else that comes across it, can see how you arrived at it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In this case, this is something we have discussed internally. The removal of bootstrap styles are in this issue: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/5926

Answer (score 2):

ng-bootstrap is an angular component library for bootstrap components. We've decided to move away from this implementation. Initially we tried to complete this before the 1.0 release, to get ride of the dependency, but we haven't been able to drop the modal before 1.0 release. We will drop the last pieces of ng-bootstrap (modal) for the 2.0 release.

This doesn't mean that we're dropping bootstrap itself (yet). We have a plan to become agnostic to various UI systems, but that's a bigger change.